# How can I use cmake to compile .fx files

Tags: directx, cmake, directx-11

According to [this MSDN blog entry](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chuckw/archive/2012/05/07/hlsl-fxc-and-d3dcompile.aspx) it is recommended to compile .fx effect files with fxc as part of your build process. Given a list of fx files, how do I tell cmake to add some to my project files (VS2010)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`find_program`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3afind_program) to find `fxc` and [`add_custom_command`](http://cmake.org/cmake/help/v2.8.9/cmake.html#command%3aadd_custom_command) to build:

```
find_program(FXC fxc DOC "fx compiler")
if(NOT FXC)
message(SEND_ERROR "Cannot find fxc.")
endif(NOT FXC)

add_custom_target(fx ALL)

foreach(FILE foo.fx bar.fx baz.fx)
  get_filename_component(FILE_WE ${FILE} NAME_WE)
  add_custom_command(OUTPUT ${FILE_WE}.obj
                     COMMAND ${FXC} /Fo ${FILE_WE}.obj ${FILE} 
                     MAIN_DEPENDENCY ${FILE}
                     COMMENT "Effect-compile ${FILE}"
                     VERBATIM)
  add_dependencies(fx ${FILE_WE}.obj)
endforeach(FILE)
```

Not being a Windows user, I'm not sure if that's exactly the right way to invoke `fxc`, but you can tinker with it. Note also that this doesn't link the object files into wherever they need to go. This [mailing list post](http://www.cmake.org/pipermail/cmake/2008-November/025541.html) might help you.

Comment: They don't need to be linked at all - they are loaded by the executable later. How can I add them to the target so they are built when their sources change?

Comment: @ltjax: Edited. Note the `add_custom_target` and the `add_dependencies` calls. Does the fx compiler output `.obj` files?

Comment: Works like a charm. Any way I can add the source files to that target so they show up in the VS solution explorer?

Comment: @ltjax: I never used the visual studio generators, so I don't know. Sorry. Perhaps the `source_group` command might do what you want.